# loading html5 video in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have a html5 video loading in Chrome.

The problem is in Chrome it shows a black background and then the video loads.How can I remove the black background.

Also in IE 10 the video background shows a different color.

My code is,

```
 <video width="975" height="650" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true">
              <source src="piston_start.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              <source src="piston_start.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

Do I need any other extension to remove the background color.Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried setting the background-color for the video element?

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I have set the background as image and it worked.I couldn't use poster as there is a delay for couple of seconds to download the video.Not sure why.Thanks.